# Jenkins shell execution error

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins.
I am trying to execute the following shell command in Cent OS:

```
ssh root@192.168.52.80 "bash -s" < ./install_x86.sh
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
[default] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson9091088582033660238.sh
+ ssh root@192.168.52.80 'bash -s'
/tmp/hudson9091088582033660238.sh: line 2: ./install_x86.sh: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Anyone any idea what I have done wrong?

**Solved**

I got it working by using the ssh plugin thats available. [Jul 17 at 15:22]

Comment: The command fails because you have no `./install_x86.sh` file

Comment: I do have install_x86.sh for some reason the "<" isn't getting read... I got it working by using the ssh plugin thats available.

Comment: Where is your `install_x86.sh` located? Did you try to add `#!/bin/bash` before your `ssh ...?`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the file `./install_x86.sh` was in a different place than jenkins' working directory.